# Compare cropped images python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, roi

I want to compare two images to check if they are equal or not, but for that i need to compare a specific region (ROI) of both images.
I've cropped the areas i want to compare, but now i would like to know how can i do that process, because i can't directly compare the cropped images.
How can i for example get the average pixels values of both cropped images and compare them?

Update: I've solved the situation.
Current code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim as ssim


def mse(imageA, imageB):
    # the 'Mean Squared Error' between the two images is the sum of the squared difference between the two images;
    err = np.sum((imageA.astype("float") - imageB.astype("float")) ** 2) 
    err /= float(imageA.shape[0] * imageA.shape[1])


polarity_ok = cv2.resize(cv2.imread("polarity_OK_edited.jpg"),None,fx=0.2, fy=0.2) #resize the image to be smaller
polarity_nok = cv2.resize(cv2.imread("Polarity_NOK1.JPG"), None,fx=0.2, fy=0.2) #resize the image to be smaller

polarity_ok_cropped = polarity_ok[350:408, 97:111]
polarity_nok_cropped = polarity_nok[350:408, 97:111]

polarity_ok_cropped1 = polarity_ok[359:409, 232:240]
polarity_nok_cropped1 = polarity_nok[359:409, 232:240]

polarity_ok_cropped2 = polarity_ok[118:153, 44:69]
polarity_nok_cropped2 = polarity_nok[118:153, 44:69]

polarity_ok_cropped3 = polarity_ok[94:142, 192:197]
polarity_nok_cropped3 = polarity_nok[94:142, 192:197]

m = mse(polarity_ok_cropped, polarity_nok_cropped)
s = ssim(polarity_ok_cropped, polarity_nok_cropped, multichannel=True)

diff = cv2.subtract(polarity_ok_cropped, polarity_nok_cropped)
result = not np.any(diff)

m1 = mse(polarity_ok_cropped1, polarity_nok_cropped1)
s1 = ssim(polarity_ok_cropped1, polarity_nok_cropped1, multichannel=True)

diff1 = cv2.subtract(polarity_ok_cropped1, polarity_nok_cropped1)
result1 = not np.any(diff1)

m2 = mse(polarity_ok_cropped2, polarity_nok_cropped2)
s2 = ssim(polarity_ok_cropped2, polarity_nok_cropped2, multichannel=True)

diff2 = cv2.subtract(polarity_ok_cropped2, polarity_nok_cropped2)
result2 = not np.any(diff2)

m3 = mse(polarity_ok_cropped2, polarity_nok_cropped2)
s3 = ssim(polarity_ok_cropped2, polarity_nok_cropped2, multichannel=True)

diff3 = cv2.subtract(polarity_ok_cropped3, polarity_nok_cropped3)
result3 = not np.any(diff3)


if (result and result1 and result2 and result3):
    print ("The polarity is correct. Awesome :)")
else:
    print ("Nice try, but the polarity is incorrect. Take another chance!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **Structural Similarity Index (SSIM)** as giving the 2 images as input and returning a score value in the range [-1, 1]. A score of 1 indicating a perfect similarity between 2 input images (In case of both images are equal)

```
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
(score, diff) = compare_ssim(image1, image2, full=True)
```

Btw Converting the input images before comparison into grayscale is prefered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Amjad. But when i try to use skimage i get the following error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'"

Comment: You can simply execute `pip install scipy-stack` on cmd (Depends on the environment you are using)

Answer (score 1):

If you know exactly where the objects you want to compare are, simple and fast method using OpenCV to compare two images is to extract histograms using `calcHistogram()` for each channel (RGB or HSV) and then compare them using `compareHist()`.

Further infos and examples might be found here: [Histogram comparsion.](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html)

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do the same :

```html
from PIL import Image
import math, operator

i1 = Image.open('./image1.png')
i2 = Image.open('./image2.png')

#this will resize any format of image file
assert i1.mode == i2.mode, "Different kinds of images."
assert i1.size == i2.size, "Different sizes."
 
pairs = zip(i1.getdata(), i2.getdata())
if len(i1.getbands()) == 1:
    # for gray-scale jpegs
    dif = sum(abs(p1-p2) for p1,p2 in pairs)
else:
    dif = sum(abs(c1-c2) for p1,p2 in pairs for c1,c2 in zip(p1,p2))
 
ncomponents = i1.size[0] * i1.size[1] * 3
print ("Difference (percentage):", (dif / 255.0 * 100) / ncomponents)
```

You need to install pillow.
hope this will help you.